# Supremum of a subharmonic function

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Le  be an open ball of $\mathbb{R}^2$, :$\mathbb{R}^2→\mathbb{R}$ a function and $\Delta$ the Laplacian operator. $m_1$ is a local maximum of $f$ in $D$.

Recall that $\forall h \in \mathbb{R}^2, d^2_{m_1}(h,h)\leq 0$ where $d^2_{m_1}$ is the second-order differential of $f$ at $m_1$.

Show that if $\Delta f >0$ on , then $\forall m \in D$, $$f(m) < \sup_{m' \in \partial D} f(m').$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer.

Since $d^2_{m_1}f(h,h) \leq 0$, the Hessian matrix of $f$ is negative in a local interior maximum of $f$ in $D$. Therefore,

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \leq 0 \text{  and  } \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \leq 0$$

So at a local interior maximum: $$\Delta f \leq 0$$

More generally, for all interior maximum of $f$ in $D$,  $$\Delta f \leq 0$$

Hence, if $\Delta f > 0$, then $f$ can only reach its maximum can't reach its maximum on an interior point  of $D$.

Finally,

$$\forall m \in D, f(m) < \sup_{m \in \partial D} f(m')$$